# File upload using Angular js and grails

Tags: angularjs, grails, file-upload

I am trying to implement a [file upload using angular js](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) and grails. I am able to call the grails controller method but not able to get the file from angular js using request.getFile() method. Here is my html code,

```
<script src="angular-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> 
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-file-upload.min.js"></script> 

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myModelObj">
  <input type="file" name="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" >
  <div ng-file-drop="onFileSelect($files)" ng-file-drag-over-class="optional-css-class"
        ng-show="dropSupported">drop files here</div>
  <div ng-file-drop-available="dropSupported=true" 
        ng-show="!dropSupported">HTML5 Drop File is not supported!</div>
  <button ng-click="upload.abort()">Cancel Upload</button>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code,

```
//inject angular file upload directives and service.
angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var file = $files[i];
      $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url: 'GrailsApp/upload', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
        data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
        file: file, // or list of files: $files for html5 only
      }).progress(function(evt) {
        console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  };
}];
```

Here is the grails controller upload method,

```
def upload() {
    def f = request.getFile('file')
    if (f.empty) {
        flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
        render(view: 'uploadForm')
        return
    }
f.transferTo(new File('D:/Filestorage/myfile.txt')) response.sendError(200, 'Done') }
```

While running this code gives a error like below,

`Request.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: {"file"}`

But definitely it is going inside the controller method. Just not able to get the file from angular js.

But the same code works when I use a gsp form like below,

```
<g:uploadForm action="upload">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</g:uploadForm>
```

The same code works like a chram and upload the file successfully.

Comment: Have you also tried explicitly adding a name to file while upload? `fileFormDataName: "myFile"` in angular and then getting the file as `request.getFile('myFile')` in Grails side.

Comment: Where I am supposed to put fileFormDataName:"myFile" ? In html or in javascript $scope.upload method ?

Comment: In `$scope.upload` as shown [here](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) in comments immediately after `file: file`.

Comment: Can you just see in firebug console if the file is really coming from ui .If it is coming it will be visible in firebug console post request

Comment: @dmahapatro That worked, I just added fileFormDataName: "myFile" parameter in my $scope.upload. Thanks for ur input

Comment: Added as an answer to make it useful for others. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs say the fileName by default is `file` but add `fileFormDataName: "myFile"` explicitly as:

```
$scope.upload = $upload.upload({
    url: 'GrailsApp/upload', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
    data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
    file: file,
    fileFormDataName: "myFile"
}).progress(function(evt) {
    console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // file is uploaded successfully
    console.log(data);
});
```

in angular and then get the file as

```
request.getFile('myFile')
```

in Grails side to see if it works.

Also see, instead of explicitly adding a `fileFormDataName` just rectify that you have removed the trailing `,` from `file: file,` and use as earlier, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been fixed. Just need to bind the post with a name, by adding fileFormDataName:"file" in the $scope.upload method.

Here is a sample,

```
//inject angular file upload directives and service.
angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var file = $files[i];
      $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url: 'GrailsApp/upload', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
        data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
        file: file,
        fileFormDataName:'file'
      }).progress(function(evt) {
        console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  };
}];
```