# File upload in Grails application using angular js

Tags: angularjs, grails, angular-file-upload

I'm working on a Grails (2.3.7) application with AngularJS. I've to upload files in my application. Since the front end is managed by Angular , I'm uploading my file from Angular controller.  I've gone through [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-upload) 
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639672/file-upload-using-angular-js-and-grails) discussions , and tried to upload as follows.

My file uploader is

```
<input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">
```

Angular controller is

```
myapp.controller('createWebController',['$scope','$http','$upload',function($scope,$http,$upload){

       $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {

                                                               var file = $files[0];
                                                               console.log(file)
                                                         $upload.upload({
                                                             url: 'UploadLogo/upload', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url

                                                             file: file,
                                                             method: 'POST' ,
                                                             fileFormDataName: "myFile",

                                                         }).progress(function(evt) {
                                                             console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                                                         }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                                             // file is uploaded successfully
                                                             console.log(data);
                                                          })
                                                                  .error(function(data){ console.log(data)})
                                                           ;

       };
```

}])

on the server , I'm using [this service](https://github.com/cavneb/FileUploader/blob/master/grails-app/services/berry/FileUploadService.groovy) and the upload handler code is

```
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile
    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder


       class UploadLogoController {
          FileUploadService fileUploadService

                 def upload() {

                     def avatarImage = request.getFile('file')
                      if (!avatarImage.isEmpty()) 
                              {
        userInstance.avatar = fileUploadService.uploadFile(avatarImage, "logo.png", "~/Desktop/upload")                                   
                              render "ok"
                              }
                             else
                               {
                                render "Empty"    

                              }

                       }
```

}

But the problem is I'm getting a `500 (Internal Server Error)`  from grails. The file is not being uploaded.

also getting response as `Cannot invoke method isEmpty() on null object`
Which means the file has not been sent to the server. Whats the problem here.. Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. You could create a custom directive for the file upload control

```
myapp.directive('ngFileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.ngFileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};}])
```

and in your html use `<input  type="file" ng-file-model="myFile" />`

Then you could create a custom service to do the file upload. Note that its not necessary to create service but it can easily reuse in later file uploads just by injecting the service.

```
myapp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl,filename){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    fd.append('filename', filename);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    })
    .error(function(data){ console.log(data)
    });
};}]);
```

The uploadFileToUrl  takes 3 arguments , the file itself , the URL to upload and the file name to be saved as.(You can customize this as you wish)  . Use the `$http.post` to post data.

Finally in your controller , include this

```
var file = $scope.myFile;
var filename = 'YourFileName'
var uploadUrl = '/UploadLogo/upload'  // don't forget to include the leading / 
fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl,filename);
```